# lazy-seq StackOverflowError

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

Why does this work

```
(def fibs (cons 0 (cons 1 (lazy-seq (map + fibs (rest fibs))))))
(take 10 fibs)
```

while this other

```
(def fibs (lazy-seq (cons 0 (cons 1 (map + fibs (rest fibs))))))
(take 10 fibs)
```

generate a StackOverflowError?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `lazy-seq`?  It seems to run fine if you just remove it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt On my repl (clojure 1.6) the code ` (def fibs (cons 0 (cons 1 (map + fibs (rest fibs)))))` does not work.  Lazy-seq is necessary I think, because it delays the computation of the stream, otherwise it won't work defining fibs in terms of fibs itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first note that it also works with one `cons` outside:

```
(def fibs (cons 0 (lazy-seq (cons 1 (map + fibs (rest fibs))))))
```

Let's also establish that `lazy-seq` is a macro (obviously, since it doesn't evaluate the arguments) and puts the `body` (the argument(s) to `lazy-seq`) into a function.

Now, if you "request" an element from that sequence that function will be called once and subsequent calls will return the cached value.

Obviously, only once that function returns something you have a value available. Now, what's happening in our bad case:

Imagine clojure is in the middle of evaluating the function for the very first time. The first thing it needs is `+`, `fibs` and `(rest fibs)` in order to pass this to cons. Now clojure will see that `fibs` is a lazy sequence and invoke it! This is because you're currently in your first invocation and haven't returned. This is causing an infinite recursion.

The fix is easy: Make sure there is a realized element in the beginning of the list so that the two expressions, `fibs` and `(rest fibs`) can return something. In particular, taking the `rest` of `(cons 1 whatever)` will return `whatever` [without realizing a single element](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d5708425995e8c83157ad49007ec2f8f43d8eac8/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Cons.java) (important since otherwise we'd have the same problem again).